# Modify scanner UI to be a rectangular portrait vs 320x480

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, phonegap-plugins, zxing

I would like to be able to modify the green box and the red strip on the scanner UI to be a rectangular scan vs a 320x480 always.

I have added debugging notes and found out that when the loadView gets called, it always sets the previewLayer's dimensions to 320x480

How can I change that?

I was able to do this in Android by editing the MIN and MAX width parameters

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with these three solution you can achieve your goal, the third option is the most efficient but the worst in code maintainability, the first, if applicable, is the best:

1. From the original repository of the iOS versions of this plugin you can find this [guide](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/DEPRECATED/iOS/BarcodeScanner#creating-and-using-custom-ui-overlay-xib) to costumize your overlay view.
2. You can try to work on the overlay directly from code, [here](http://slackshotindustries.blogspot.it/2013/04/creating-custom-overlays-in-xzing.html) you can find a way to do that.
3. Finally you can fork the GIthub project and work directly to the affected  [source](https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner/blob/master/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm#L954), in this case in the method `(UIImage*)buildReticleImage` contains all you need to change this behavior.

Hope this help!

Comment: So I finally figured out how to make the reticle full width (I know I'm learning) but even now, it would not scan high density barcodes longer than 10 chars. I think its because of the contrast, how can I edit the contrast and shutter speed?

Comment: I've used this library for quarcode, for barcode i find it very difficult to make it works in some devices, and i think too that the problem is releated to the contrast.
For this reason i migrate to Zbar, [here](https://github.com/PaoloMessina/csZBar) you can find my fork if you want to try it.